# Creating a stream of values while calling async fns?

Tags: rust, async-await, stream

I can't figure out how to provide a [`Stream`](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/futures-api-docs/0.3.0-alpha.14/futures/stream/index.html) where I `await` async functions to get the data needed for the values of the stream.

I've tried to implement the the [`Stream`](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/futures-api-docs/0.3.0-alpha.14/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#tymethod.poll_next) trait directly, but I run into issues because I'd like to use async things like `await`ing, the compiler does not want me to call async functions.

I assume that I'm missing some background on what the goal of `Stream` is and I'm just attacking this incorrectly and perhaps I shouldn't be looking at `Stream` at all, but I don't know where else to turn. I've seen the other [functions in the `stream` module](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/futures-api-docs/0.3.0-alpha.14/futures/stream/index.html#functions) that could be useful, but I'm unsure how I could store any state and use these functions.

As a slightly simplified version of my actual goal, I want to provide a stream of 64-byte `Vec`s from an `AsyncRead` object (i.e. TCP stream), but also store a little state inside whatever logic ends up producing values for the stream, in this example, a counter.

```
pub struct Receiver<T>
where
    T: AsyncRead + Unpin,
{
    readme: T,
    num: u64,
}

// ..code for a simple `new() -> Self` function..

impl<T> Stream for Receiver<T>
where
    T: AsyncRead + Unpin,
{
    type Item = Result<Vec<u8>, io::Error>;

    fn poll_next(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let mut buf: [u8; 64] = [0; 64];
        match self.readme.read_exact(&mut buf).await {
            Ok(()) => {
                self.num += 1;
                Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(buf.to_vec())))
            }
            Err(e) => Poll::Ready(Some(Err(e))),
        }
    }
}
```

This fails to build, saying

```
error[E0728]: `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
```

I'm using `rustc 1.36.0-nightly (d35181ad8 2019-05-20)` and my `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
[dependencies]
futures-preview = { version = "0.3.0-alpha.16", features = ["compat", "io-compat"] }
pin-utils = "0.1.0-alpha.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer copy/pasted from the [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/c3wkx6/async_stream_of_values_using_async_fns_to_produce/) by user [Matthias247](https://www.reddit.com/user/Matthias247):

> It's unfortunately not possible at the moment - Streams have to be implemented by hand and can not utilize async fn. Whether it's possible to change this in the future is unclear.
>
> You can work around it by defining a different Stream trait which makes use of Futures like:
>
> ```
> trait Stream<T> { 
>    type NextFuture: Future<Output=T>;
>
>    fn next(&mut self) -> Self::NextFuture; 
> }
> ```
>
> [This article](https://gist.github.com/Matthias247/5e5e7430149bbb04eebf18cf31747fe0) and [this futures-rs issue](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/issues/1365) have more information around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [gen-stream](https://crates.io/crates/gen-stream) crate:

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait, gen_future)]

use {
    futures::prelude::*,
    gen_stream::{gen_await, GenTryStream},
    pin_utils::unsafe_pinned,
    std::{
        io,
        marker::PhantomData,
        pin::Pin,
        sync::{
            atomic::{AtomicU64, Ordering},
            Arc,
        },
        task::{Context, Poll},
    },
};

pub type Inner = Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<Vec<u8>, io::Error>> + Send>>;

pub struct Receiver<T> {
    inner: Inner,
    pub num: Arc<AtomicU64>,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Receiver<T> {
    unsafe_pinned!(inner: Inner);
}

impl<T> From<T> for Receiver<T>
where
    T: AsyncRead + Unpin + Send + 'static,
{
    fn from(mut readme: T) -> Self {
        let num = Arc::new(AtomicU64::new(0));

        Self {
            inner: Box::pin(GenTryStream::from({
                let num = num.clone();
                static move || loop {
                    let mut buf: [u8; 64] = [0; 64];
                    match gen_await!(readme.read_exact(&mut buf)) {
                        Ok(()) => {
                            num.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
                            yield Poll::Ready(buf.to_vec())
                        }
                        Err(e) => return Err(e),
                    }
                }
            })),
            num,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Stream for Receiver<T>
where
    T: AsyncRead + Unpin,
{
    type Item = Result<Vec<u8>, io::Error>;

    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        self.inner().poll_next(cx)
    }
}
```