# Is there any way to create a async stream generator that yields the result of repeatedly calling a function?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I want to build a program that collects weather updates and represents them as a stream. I want to call `get_weather()` in an infinite loop, with 60 seconds delay between **finish** and **start**.

A simplified version would look like this:

```
async fn get_weather() -> Weather { /* ... */ }

fn get_weather_stream() -> impl futures::Stream<Item = Weather> {
    loop {
        tokio::timer::delay_for(std::time::Duration::from_secs(60)).await;
        let weather = get_weather().await;
        yield weather; // This is not supported
        // Note: waiting for get_weather() stops the timer and avoids overflows.
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this easily?

Using `tokio::timer::Interval` will not work when `get_weather()` takes more than 60 seconds:

```
fn get_weather_stream() -> impl futures::Stream<Item = Weather> {
    tokio::timer::Interval::new_with_delay(std::time::Duration::from_secs(60))
        .then(|| get_weather())
}
```

If that happens, the next function will start immediately. I want to keep exactly 60 seconds between the previous `get_weather()` start and the next `get_weather()` start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`stream::unfold`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/fn.unfold.html) to go from the "world of futures" to the "world of streams". We don't need any extra state, so we use the empty tuple:

```
use futures::StreamExt; // 0.3.4
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time; // 0.2.11

struct Weather;

async fn get_weather() -> Weather {
    Weather
}

const BETWEEN: Duration = Duration::from_secs(1);

fn get_weather_stream() -> impl futures::Stream<Item = Weather> {
    futures::stream::unfold((), |_| async {
        time::delay_for(BETWEEN).await;
        let weather = get_weather().await;
        Some((weather, ()))
    })
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    get_weather_stream()
        .take(3)
        .for_each(|_v| async {
            println!("Got the weather");
        })
        .await;
}
```

```
% time ./target/debug/example

Got the weather
Got the weather
Got the weather

real    3.085   3085495us
user    0.004   3928us
sys     0.003   3151us
```

See also:

- [How do I convert an iterator into a stream on success or an empty stream on failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51114794/155423)
- [How do I iterate over a Vec of functions returning Futures in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50850309/155423)
- [Creating a stream of values while calling async fns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56719990/155423)

Comment: Is there any way to allow passing a variable to `get_weather()` by reference? I want to pass it to `get_weather_stream()` and then to `get_weather()` in each iteration. Of course the resulting Stream should be lifetime dependent on that variable.

Comment: @peku33 I don't see immediately why it wouldn't work. Perhaps you should try it and report back!

Comment: In the first step I added `<'a>(arg: &'a i32)` to both functions. I also added `+ 'a` to `get_weather_stream` return. However I get `closure may outlive current function`. I would like not to use Arc, Rc, etc if possible.

Comment: @peku33 [seems to work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c1bc55fa074cd53da526172c72afc733)