# How to implement streams from future functions

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-async-std

in order to understand how streams work I was trying to implement an infinite number generator that uses random.org. The first thing I did, was implementing a version where I would call an async function called get_number and it would fill a buffer and return the next possible number:

```rust
struct RandomGenerator {
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
    position: usize,
}

impl RandomGenerator {
    pub fn new() -> RandomGenerator {
        Self {
            buffer: Vec::new(),
            position: 0,
        }
    }

    pub async fn get_number(&mut self) -> u8 {
        self.fill_buffer().await;

        let value = self.buffer[self.position];
        self.position += 1;

        value
    }

    async fn fill_buffer(&mut self) {
        if self.buffer.is_empty() || self.is_buffer_depleted() {
            let new_numbers = self.fetch_numbers().await;
            drop(replace(&mut self.buffer, new_numbers));
            self.position = 0;
        }
    }

    fn is_buffer_depleted(&self) -> bool {
        self.buffer.len() >= self.position
    }

    async fn fetch_numbers(&mut self) -> Vec<u8> {
        let response = reqwest::get("https://www.random.org/integers/?num=10&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new").await.unwrap();
        let numbers = response.text().await.unwrap();
        numbers
            .lines()
            .map(|line| line.trim().parse::<u8>().unwrap())
            .collect()
    }
}
```

with this implementation, I can call the function `get_number` on a loop and get as many numbers I want but the idea was to have iterators so I can call a bunch of composition functions like `take`, `take_while`, and others.

But the moment I try to implement a Stream, the problems start to rise:
My first try was to have a struct that would hold a reference to the generator

```rust
struct RandomGeneratorStream<'a> {
    generator: &'a mut RandomGenerator,
}
```

and then I've implemented the following Stream

```rust
impl<'a> Stream for RandomGeneratorStream<'a> {
    type Item = u8;

    fn poll_next(
        self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> std::task::Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let f = self.get_mut().generator.get_number();
        pin_mut!(f);
        f.poll_unpin(cx).map(Some)
    }
}
```

but calling this would just hang the process

```rust
generator.into_stream().take(18).collect::<Vec<u8>>().await
```

On the next tries, I tried to hold a state of the future on the stream struct using pin_mut! but ended up having many errors with lifetimes without being able to solve them.
What can be done in that case?
Here is a working code without the streams:

```rust
use std::mem::replace;
struct RandomGenerator {
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
    position: usize,
}

impl RandomGenerator {
    pub fn new() -> RandomGenerator {
        Self {
            buffer: Vec::new(),
            position: 0,
        }
    }

    pub async fn get_number(&mut self) -> u8 {
        self.fill_buffer().await;

        let value = self.buffer[self.position];
        self.position += 1;

        value
    }

    async fn fill_buffer(&mut self) {
        if self.buffer.is_empty() || self.is_buffer_depleted() {
            let new_numbers = self.fetch_numbers().await;
            drop(replace(&mut self.buffer, new_numbers));
            self.position = 0;
        }
    }

    fn is_buffer_depleted(&self) -> bool {
        self.buffer.len() >= self.position
    }

    async fn fetch_numbers(&mut self) -> Vec<u8> {
        let response = reqwest::get("https://www.random.org/integers/?num=10&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new").await.unwrap();
        let numbers = response.text().await.unwrap();
        numbers
            .lines()
            .map(|line| line.trim().parse::<u8>().unwrap())
            .collect()
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut generator = RandomGenerator::new();
    dbg!(generator.get_number().await);
}
```

Here you can find a link to the first working sample (instead of calling random.org I've used a Cursor because dns resolution was not working on the playground) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=730eaf1f7db842877d3f3e7ca1c6d2a5

And my last try with streams you can find here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de0b212ee70865f6ac6c19430cd952cd

Comment: btw, your working version just returns `1` repeatedly since the `>=` in `is_buffer_depleted` should be `<=`

Comment: also, `drop(replace(&mut self.buffer, new_numbers))` is the same thing as `self.buffer = new_numbers`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On the next tries, I tried to hold a state of the future on the stream struct using pin_mut! but ended up having many errors with lifetimes without being able to solve them.

You were on the right track, you would need to persist the future in order for `poll_next` to work properly.

Unfortunately, you'll run into a roadblock with mutable references. You're keeping a `&mut RandomGenerator` in order to use it repeatedly, but the future itself also has to keep a `&mut RandomGenerator` for it to do its job. This would violate the exclusivity of mutable references. Any way you cut it will likely face this problem.

The better way to go from `Future`s to a `Stream` is to follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700741/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-async-stream-generator-that-yields-the-result-of-re) and use [`futures::stream::unfold`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/fn.unfold.html):

```
fn as_stream<'a>(&'a mut self) -> impl Stream<Item = u8> + 'a {
    futures::stream::unfold(self, |rng| async {
        let number = rng.get_number().await;
        Some((number, rng))
    })
}
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=857c5d1c5d19ba074f59903e15747d13).

This may not necessarily help you learn more about streams, but the provided functions are usually better than hand-rolling. The key reason this avoids the multiple-mutable-references problem above is because the function generating the future *takes ownership* of the mutable reference, and then gives it back when its done. That way only one exists at a time. Even if you implemented `Stream` yourself, you'd have to use a similar mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will take a look at how Unfold is implemented in order to understand it a bit better.