# How to create a tokio Stream that repeatedly calls an async method

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am trying to implement `tokio::stream::Stream` on a struct that should repeatedly produce the result of calling an async method on that same struct. I am having a difficult time trying to get the lifetimes to work out. Here is the code that I have so far:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Poll, Context};
use futures::ready;
use hyper::{
    client::{Client, HttpConnector},
    body::Body,
};
use pin_project::pin_project;
use tokio::stream::{Stream, StreamExt};

// Placeholder for actual result type
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyResult;

#[pin_project]
struct ResultProducer {
    client: Client<HttpConnector, Body>,
    #[pin]
    current_request: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=MyResult>>>>,
}

impl ResultProducer {
    fn new() -> ResultProducer {
        ResultProducer {
            client: Client::new(),
            current_request: None,
        }
    }

    // This is the method that should be called repeatedly
    async fn next_result(&self) -> MyResult {
        let url = "http://www.example.com".parse().unwrap();
        let _ = self.client.get(url).await.unwrap();

        MyResult
    }
}

impl Stream for ResultProducer {
    type Item = MyResult;

    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let mut fut = self.project().current_request;

        if fut.is_none() {
            fut.set(Some(Box::pin(self.next_result())));
        }

        let res = ready!(fut.as_mut().as_pin_mut().unwrap().poll(cx));
        fut.set(None);

        Poll::Ready(Some(res))
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let requester = ResultProducer::new();
    while let Some(res) = requester.next().await {
        println!("Got a result: {:?}", res);
    }
}
```

When I try compiling this, I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:46:40
   |
46 |             fut.set(Some(Box::pin(self.next_result())));
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems like the compiler thinks that the future returned from `next_result` could outlive the `ResultProducer` instance and wants it to have a `'static` lifetime, but it seems like this should be possible. What am I doing wrong here?

### Update

Based on the related questions

- [Creating a stream of values while calling async fns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56719990/155423)
- [How to implement a `Future` / `Stream` that polls `async fn(&mut self)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61295176/155423)
- [Is there any way to create a async stream generator that yields the result of repeatedly calling a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58700741/155423)

I can see that *there is no safe way* to guarantee that the `&self` reference taken by `next_result` will be valid on any given call to `poll` on the future that it returns.

In the case of the code that I am writing, I can guarantee that the referent will not be dropped, so I *could* perform an unsafe cast of a self reference to give it an arbitrary lifetime, but I decided to go the safe route and extract the state that this method needs into another struct and let `ResultProducer` own an `Arc` of this struct (actually an `Arc<Mutex<...>>` since I need mutable access in my actual code). The `async` function then takes the `Arc<Mutex<...>>`, which it can safely access, since the lifetime is no longer tied to `self`.

This is the general approach suggested in the accepted answer to [How to implement a `Future` / `Stream` that polls `async fn(&mut self)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61295176/155423)

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Creating a stream of values while calling async fns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56719990/155423); [How to implement a `Future` / `Stream` that polls `async fn(&mut self)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61295176/155423); [Is there any way to create a async stream generator that yields the result of repeatedly calling a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58700741/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Thanks, @Shepmaster. This question has no substantial differences from https://stackoverflow.com/q/61295176/155423 and can be closed as soon as the bounty expires.